# Symfony embed edit controller not working

Tags: forms, symfony, controller, render

I'm trying to have an edit form in a modal but this edit form is not working in the context.

It is working when I try the form directy in a webpage using the URI address but it is not when I try it in my page context. I'm gonna explain more ...

In my webpage, I have a `render controller` :

```
    <div class="card">
        <div class="body">
            {{ render(controller('AppBundle:Classeur3:vacation', {'request':app.request , 'id': zone.id})) }}
        </div>
    </div>
```

This controller retrieve somme Entities and display a table as following :

```
<table id="sites-list" class="table table-bordered datatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Employé</th>
            <th>Heure d'entrée</th>
            <th>Heure de sortie</th>
            <th>Durée</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for v in vacations %}
            <tr id="tr-vacation-{{ v.id }}">
                <td>{{ v.user }}</td>
                <td>{{ v.entryTime|date }}</td>
                <td>{{ v.exitTime|date }}</td>
                <td>{{ v.totalTime }}</td>
                <td style="width: 150px;">
                    <button onclick="$('#modal').modal({remote: '{{ path('edit_vacation', {'id': v.id}) }}' });" type="button" class="btn btn-circle waves-effect waves-circle waves-float" style="margin-right: 5px;">
                        <i class="material-icons">search</i>
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My `edit_vacation` ressource is defined bby the following route :

```
edit_vacation:
    path:     /vacation/{id}/edit
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Classeur3:editVacation }
```

This is my controller function :

```
public function editVacationAction(Request $request, $id){

    $vacation       = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Answ31Vacation::class)->find($id);
    $form           = $this->createForm(Answ31VacationType::class, $vacation);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($vacation);
        $entityManager->flush();

        //Message
        $this->addFlash('success', 'Vacation mise à jours');

        //Redirect to Zone edit page
        return $this->redirectToRoute('zone_edit', array('id' => $vacation->getZone()->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('AppBundle:Classeur3:edit_vacation.html.twig', array(
        "form" => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

And here is my view :

```
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                {{ form(form) }}
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</button>
    </div>
```

The modal is perfectly displayed, but when I submit the form, the page is reloaded as planed but the data are not updated.
When I try to call directly in URL my ressource ( baseurl/vacation/1/edit )  I have the form and the modifications are working, when I press my submit button the data are updated.

Any thought ?

Comment: Does it work when you open your modal on a page on which there is not another form?

Comment: Your render statement seems to point to a vacation method while your code seems to show editVacationAction?  But more importantly, view the html source in your browser and see where the form is posting to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `editVacationAction` you should try setting the target action of your form, like this

```
$form = $this->createForm(Answ31VacationType::class, $vacation, ["action"=>$this->generateUrl('edit_vacation']);
```

But when you submit, the page will change and you will loose the modal without some extra JavaScript.

Comment: I don't know why but the action was not automaticaly added to my form. It is now i'm using your solution. Thanks !

Comment: @Gauthier symfony per default does not add the action to the form, expecting it is the same url of the current page. But in your case you are rendering the form in a sub request, so the target action of the form must be specified because it differs from the current page url.